# How to automate the process of Importing data from OneDrive to ADLS gen 2/blob storage?

Tags: database, azure, automation, onedrive, data-ingestion

I am working on a project which requires regular ingestion of data from MS Excel (which is stored in OneDrive) to a cloud storage like ADLS gen 2 or Blob storage gen 2.

I came across a few articles which requires use of logic apps, but I cannot find any alternate solutions (if there are any).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Power Automate flow [Copy new files to AzureBlob from a OneDrive for Business folder.](https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/galleries/public/templates/49933434732d4846a1fc0aaae72f8998/copy-new-files-to-azureblob-from-a-onedrive-for-business-folder/).

Connect Azure Blob storage with Access key authentication:

[image]

Connect to OneDrive account:

[image]

Select file sources and destinations:

[image]

After selecting all, run the flow, and it will copy the files successfully to the Blob account.